# Hearthstone keeps crashing on Lutris on Ubuntu

Tags: hearthstone, ubuntu, wine

I just installed Lutris to play Hearthstone on Ubuntu. Battle.net launcher and the game launches, the bar door screen, Hearthstone text, settings and social buttons appear then the game shuts down.

I went through the log file but I cannot extract any further information than something is wrong with Vulkan API.

This is from the logs of the Lutris:

```
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
[0211/004418.913:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(156)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
info:  Game: Battle.net.exe
info:  DXVK: d9vk-0.40.1-croakacola-zero
info:  Built-in extension providers:
info:    Win32 WSI
info:    OpenVR
warn:  OpenVR: Failed to locate module
info:  Enabled instance extensions:
info:    VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2
info:    VK_KHR_surface
info:    VK_KHR_win32_surface
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
warn:  D3D9: VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM_S8_UINT -> VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT
info:  GeForce GT 650M:
info:    Driver: 440.59.0
info:    Vulkan: 1.1.119
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 1024 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[7]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:      Memory Type[8]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]: 
info:      Size: 11927 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[5]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[6]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[9]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[10]: Property Flags = 0xe
warn:  D3D9: VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM_S8_UINT -> VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT
info:  Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile:
info:    Driver: 19.2.8
info:    Vulkan: 1.1.102
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 1536 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0xf
info:  Process set as DPI aware
info:  Game: Battle.net.exe
info:  DXVK: v1.5.4
info:  Built-in extension providers:
info:    Win32 WSI
info:    OpenVR
warn:  OpenVR: Failed to locate module
info:  Enabled instance extensions:
info:    VK_KHR_surface
info:    VK_KHR_win32_surface
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
info:  GeForce GT 650M:
info:    Driver: 440.59.0
info:    Vulkan: 1.1.119
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 1024 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[7]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:      Memory Type[8]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]: 
info:      Size: 11927 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[5]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[6]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[9]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[10]: Property Flags = 0xe
info:  Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile:
info:    Driver: 19.2.8
info:    Vulkan: 1.1.102
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 1536 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0xf
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Probing D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Using feature level D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  Device properties:
info:    Device name:     : GeForce GT 650M
info:    Driver version   : 440.59.0
info:  Enabled device extensions:
info:    VK_EXT_depth_clip_enable
info:    VK_EXT_host_query_reset
info:    VK_EXT_shader_demote_to_helper_invocation
info:    VK_EXT_transform_feedback
info:    VK_EXT_vertex_attribute_divisor
info:    VK_KHR_create_renderpass2
info:    VK_KHR_depth_stencil_resolve
info:    VK_KHR_draw_indirect_count
info:    VK_KHR_driver_properties
info:    VK_KHR_image_format_list
info:    VK_KHR_sampler_mirror_clamp_to_edge
info:    VK_KHR_swapchain
info:  Device features:
info:    robustBufferAccess                     : 1
info:    fullDrawIndexUint32                    : 1
info:    imageCubeArray                         : 1
info:    independentBlend                       : 1
info:    geometryShader                         : 1
info:    tessellationShader                     : 1
info:    sampleRateShading                      : 1
info:    dualSrcBlend                           : 1
info:    logicOp                                : 1
info:    multiDrawIndirect                      : 1
info:    drawIndirectFirstInstance              : 1
info:    depthClamp                             : 1
info:    depthBiasClamp                         : 1
info:    fillModeNonSolid                       : 1
info:    depthBounds                            : 1
info:    multiViewport                          : 1
info:    samplerAnisotropy                      : 1
info:    textureCompressionBC                   : 1
info:    occlusionQueryPrecise                  : 1
info:    pipelineStatisticsQuery                : 1
info:    vertexPipelineStoresAndAtomics         : 1
info:    fragmentStoresAndAtomics               : 1
info:    shaderImageGatherExtended              : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageExtendedFormats      : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageReadWithoutFormat    : 0
info:    shaderStorageImageWriteWithoutFormat   : 1
info:    shaderClipDistance                     : 1
info:    shaderCullDistance                     : 1
info:    shaderFloat64                          : 1
info:    shaderInt64                            : 1
info:    variableMultisampleRate                : 1
info:  VK_EXT_conditional_rendering
info:    conditionalRendering                   : 1
info:  VK_EXT_depth_clip_enable
info:    depthClipEnable                        : 1
info:  VK_EXT_host_query_reset
info:    hostQueryReset                         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_memory_priority
info:    memoryPriority                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_shader_demote_to_helper_invocation
info:    shaderDemoteToHelperInvocation         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_transform_feedback
info:    transformFeedback                      : 1
info:    geometryStreams                        : 1
info:  VK_EXT_vertex_attribute_divisor
info:    vertexAttributeInstanceRateDivisor     : 1
info:    vertexAttributeInstanceRateZeroDivisor : 1
info:  Queue families:
info:    Graphics : 0
info:    Transfer : 1
info:  DXVK: Read 43 valid state cache entries
info:  DXVK: Using 5 compiler threads
info:  DXGI: NvAPI workaround enabled, reporting AMD GPU
info:  Adapter LUID 0: 0:9c2
info:  DXGI: NvAPI workaround enabled, reporting AMD GPU
err:   D3D11DXGIResource::GetSharedHandle: Stub
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  9d8e1289-d7b3-465f-8126-250e349af85d
info:  Presenter: Actual swap chain properties:
info:    Format:       VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
info:    Present mode: VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR
info:    Buffer size:  104x1
info:    Image count:  2
info:    Exclusive FS: 2
warn:  DXGI: MakeWindowAssociation: Ignoring flags
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  9d8e1289-d7b3-465f-8126-250e349af85d
err:   D3D11DXGIResource::GetSharedHandle: Stub
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  9d8e1289-d7b3-465f-8126-250e349af85d
info:  Presenter: Actual swap chain properties:
info:    Format:       VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
info:    Present mode: VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR
info:    Buffer size:  1200x750
info:    Image count:  2
info:    Exclusive FS: 2
warn:  DXGI: MakeWindowAssociation: Ignoring flags
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  9d8e1289-d7b3-465f-8126-250e349af85d
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
info:  Presenter: Actual swap chain properties:
info:    Format:       VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
info:    Present mode: VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR
info:    Buffer size:  1200x750
info:    Image count:  3
info:    Exclusive FS: 2
[0211/004425.805:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(156)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
[0211/004433.958:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(221)] Waited 7 ms for network service
Waiting on children
Waiting on children
Waiting on children

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Device, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Device, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) <Module>.GetReady()
2020-02-11 00:44:46,221: Unable to read stat for process 10070
2020-02-11 00:44:46,222: Unable to read stat for process 10070
All children gone
Exit with returncode 0
```

Comment: `INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete` looks concerning. It might be that Lutris can't support this sort of thing yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For those experiencing the same error, what you need to do is:

- Go to Lutris launcher
- Select Hearthstone
- Under `Play` button, click `Configure`
- You need to add this to `DLL Overrides` under `Runner Options`:

  **Key**: locationapi.dll | **Value**: disabled

and it should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for making my day better!

Comment: Suprised this worked on manjaro as well thank you!

Comment: The `FileNotFoundException` error appeared randomly for me today and this solved it!